# Confused about get_rays function in NeRF

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I've been trying to understand NeRF. I finished reading the paper(Tancik) and watched some of the videos. I have been looking at some parts of the code. However, I can't quite wrap my head around what the get_rays function does in terms of the code. Could anybody just run through line-by-line about what each line in the the get_rays function is supposed to do?

```
def get_rays(H,W , focal, c2w): #c2w is pose
    i, j = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(W, dtype=tf.float32), tf.range(H, dtype=tf.float32), indexing='xy') 
    dirs = tf.stack([(i-W*.5)/focal, -(j-H*.5)/focal, -tf.ones_like(i)], -1)                
    rays_d = tf.reduce_sum(dirs[..., np.newaxis, :] * c2w[:3,:3], -1)     
    rays_o = tf.broadcast_to(c2w[:3,-1], tf.shape(rays_d))
    return rays_o, rays_d
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a camera position with its intrincis, `get_rays` returns all rays which start from the center of this camera and go through every pixel.

Here is the line-by-line explanation:

- line1: generate every pixel using image width and height
- line2: generate directions for every pixel (you might refer to pinhole camera model)
- line3: change the directions from camera coordinate to world coordinate
- line4: every pixel shares the same origin (already in world coordinate)

Here is a figure from NeRF-- which can offer better understanding.
[image: This figure is from NeRF--]

Answer (score 0):

It creates two lists, `rays_o` represents points where rays originate (camera centre) and `rays_d` represents direction vectors of each ray casting through the centre of every pixel of the camera. In this case, all values in the `rays_o` are the same because the function gets rays from a single camera.